# Change button value javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a script that builds a html box to input values to use in the script afterwards.  Before I used input text.  But the values inserted were often wrong, which caused annoyance by the users.  And me.

So I want to use a button instead of text input.  The button has to toggle between two or more values when clicked.  Then when I submit the form, the values have to be passed to the script.

But the onclick doesn't seem to work.  What am I missing?
The variable "vervanger" is put in place of "vervanger2" in the html box.
I get the button in my browser but nothing happens when I click on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 var lijst=[];

 function selector(){
 for (i=0;i<vervanger1;i++){
 if (document.getElementById(i).checked==true){
   lijst.push(document.getElementById(i).value);
   }
   if (document.getElementById(i).name.toString().split(":")[0]=="overzicht"||document.getElementById(i).name.toString().split(":")[0]=="evalueer"){
   lijst.push(document.getElementById(i).name+":"+document.getElementById(i).value);
   }
    }
google.script.run.handleFormSubmit(lijst);
}

function change(e){
var btn = document.getElementById(e);
btn.value = 'my value'; // will just add a hidden value
btn.innerHTML = 'my text';



}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<br />
<br />
    <FORM NAME="myform" onSubmit="selector()">
          
          <input type="button" onclick="change(0)" size="3"  id="0" style="text-align: center"  name="Eval" value="E" /input>TEST STRING<br />
               
          
        <br />
        <br />
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="OK" />
    </FORM>
   
</body>
```

Comment: Where your vervanger variable is declared ? If you posted all the code, the error is normal because you try to do something with a null variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have got your button type wrong.

> `<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="OK" />`
>
> This will post your form.

Change it to `"button"` and you should be good to go..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  Thanks to various other posts on Stackoverflow.
Now I'm able to toggle between values by pushing the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 var lijst=[];

 function selector(){
 for (i=0;i<vervanger1;i++){
 if (document.getElementById(i).checked==true){
   lijst.push(document.getElementById(i).value);
   }
   if (document.getElementById(i).name.toString().split(":")[0]=="overzicht"||document.getElementById(i).name.toString().split(":")[0]=="evalueer"){
   lijst.push(document.getElementById(i).name+":"+document.getElementById(i).value);
   }
    }
google.script.run.handleFormSubmit(lijst);
}

function change(e,choices){
var btn = document.getElementById(e);
var chs=choices.toString().split("/");
var check="nee";
for (c=0;c<chs.length;c++){
if (chs[c]===btn.value){
check="ja";
var nr=c;
}
}

if (check=="ja"&&nr<chs.length-1){

btn.value=chs[nr+1];
}else{
btn.value=chs[0];
}




}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<br />
<br />
    <FORM NAME="myform" onSubmit="selector()">
          
          <input type="button" onclick="change(0,'A/B/C')" size="3"  id="0" style="text-align: center"  name="Eval" value="E" /input>TEST STRING<br />
                      <input type="button" onclick="change(1,'A/B/C')" size="3"  id="1" style="text-align: center"  name="Eval" value="E" /input>TEST STRING<br />
   
          
        <br />
        <br />
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="OK" />
    </FORM>
   
</body>
```